# Azure Data Factory - Date Expression in component 'derived column' for last 7 Days

Tags: date, expression, azure-data-factory

I am very new to Azure Data Factory. I have created a simple Pipeline using the same source and target table. The pipeline is supposed to take the date column from the source table, apply an expression to the column date (datatype date as shown in the schema below) in the source table, and it is supposed to either load 1 if the date is within the last 7 days or 0 otherwise in the column last_7_days (as in schema).
[image: pipeline]

The schema for both source and target tables look like this:
[image: schema source and target]

Now, I am facing a challenge to write an expression in the component DerivedColumn. I have managed to find out the date which is 7 days ago with the expression: [image].

In summary, the idea is to load last_7_days column in target Table with value '1' if date >= current date - interval 7 day and date <= current date like in SQL.I would be very grateful, if anyone could help me with any tips and suggestions. If you require further information, please let me know.

Just for more information: source/target table column date is static with 10 years of date from 2020 till 2030 in yyyy-mm-dd format. ETL should run everyday and only put value 1 to the last 7 days: column last_7_days looking back from current date. Other entries must recieve value 0.

Comment: I have used case ( date == currentDate(),1, date >= subDays(currentDate(),7),1, date <subDays(currentDate(),7,0, date > currentDate(),0) as expression values. However I think there should be another elegant way.

Comment: No, there isn't. To achieve our request, Data Flow expression can be complex.it may be comprised with many functions. `case()`  function is the best one for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You currently use the expression bellow:

```
case ( date == currentDate(),1, date >= subDays(currentDate(),7),1, date <subDays(currentDate(),7,0, date > currentDate(),0)
```

If we were you, we will also choose case() function to build the expression.

About you question in comment, I'm afraid no, there isn't an another elegant way for. To achieve our request, Data Flow expression can be complex. It may be comprised with many functions. [case()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-expression-functions#case) function is the best one for you.
[image]

It's very clear and easy to understand.